# getting null in URL in OAuthRequestTokenTask in Twitter in Android?

Tags: android, twitter

I am working on Android app in which I need to post text message on twitter.
Its very easy task and I did that earlier in one shot perfectly but now I am getting a unknown stoppage. Application  hang on at "Authenticating please wait" dialog.

While debugging I got to know that in **OAuthRequestTokenTask** activity during **doInBackground(Void... params)** method the URL becomes **null** and I get exception.

Please suggest me, whats going on, in my code?????

**EDITED:** I am getting null in **OAuthRequestTokenTask** Class in the below method:

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            **final String url = provider.retrieveRequestToken(consumer, Constants.OAUTH_CALLBACK_URL);**
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url)).setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY | Intent.FLAG_FROM_BACKGROUND);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e+ "========");
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Comment: ok Sir.....!! Please if you can help me on this post.

Comment: please post your OAuthRequestTokenTask activity and show us the point at  which you get null point.

Comment: Please see my edited post above, I have posted the method above.

Answer (score 0):

I got the success in the above task.

The mistake which I was doing was, not providing the call back URL for application on my Twitter account. 
:)